# Hive - Adding comments to tables

Tags: hive, metadata

When I try to add comments to my Hive table,

```
ALTER TABLE table1 SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = new_comment);
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:64 mismatched input 'new_comment' expecting StringLiteral near '=' in specifying key/value property
```

Anyone know how to properly add a comment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment needs to be a quoted string. For example, these should work:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = 'Hello World!');

ALTER TABLE table1 SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = "Hello World!");
```